# current url web app link doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script

(warning: I am very new to this process)

I have been working on a script to create a charts dashboard linked to a spreadsheet. After 2 days of tutorials and forums, I have had a breakthrough--or so I thought.

The script works, at least I believe it does. There are two scenarios:

1) Publish --> Deploy as web app --> Update --> Test web for your latest code (This process/link works perfectly)

2) Publish --> Deploy as web app --> Update --> **copy & paste** Current web app URL (This process/link does not work)

I'm not sure what the difference is, except that I read there are some access difference to /dev and /exec. From what I gather, I need the 2nd process/link to work so that I can have user access the Google Site for this display of charts dashboard.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your first option (Test web for your latest code) corresponds to the actual saved state of your script, the second one depends on the latest version you created/saved using the version  save option

[image]

You have created at least one first version before being able to publish it... this is the one this link is using and it has the errors you began with...

Just save a new version eventually with a name to remind you what changed 
[image]

and update the deployment url with the latest version number.
[image]

Now you can share this url (.exec) and eventually continue to develop your app (using the .dev url) without disturbing other users with your experiments ;-)