# Make web app from google spreadsheet with GS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with some google script (code.gs) and sidebar with html buttons (index.html) , working with script.
Please explain me if it possible how I can make a web app from all this?
I want make a web app just for more simple interface on HTML.

code.gs

```
   function goalmod (){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+5", "dd.MM.YY HH:mm");
  var row = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var r = ss.getRange(row, 7, 1, 3);
  var rValues = r.getValues();
  r.setValues([["", formattedDate, rValues[0][2] +" / "+rValues[0][0]+" "+rValues[0][1]]]);
  ss.setActiveRange(ss.getRange(row, 7));
}


function technologi (){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var cell = ss.getRange(row, 7);
  cell.setValue('Technologist');
}


function economists (){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var cell = ss.getRange(row, 7);
  cell.setValue('Economists');
}


function countnum (){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var cell = ss.getRange(row, 7);
  var nomerscheta = ss.getRange(row, 13).getValue();
  cell.setValue('Count'+" "+nomerscheta);
}


function ZPutechnologov (){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var cell = ss.getRange(row, 7);
  var ZPnum = ss.getRange(row, 12).getValue();
  cell.setValue('ZP'+" "+ZPnum+'gave to technologist');
}


function goal1 ()
{
goalmod();
technologi();
}


function goal2 ()
{
goalmod();
economists();
}


function goal3 ()
{
goalmod();
countnum();
}


function goal0 ()
{
goalmod();
ZPutechnologov();
}

function newzakaz() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
 var lastDateCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 10);
 var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 10);
 rangeToCopy.copyTo(lastDateCell);

  var city = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 4);
 var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 4);
 rangeToCopy.copyTo(city);

  var tel = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 5);
 var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 5);
 rangeToCopy.copyTo(tel);

  var mail = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 6);
 var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 6);
 rangeToCopy.copyTo(mail);

  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+5", "dd.MM.YY HH:mm");
  var DateCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 8);
  DateCell.setValue(formattedDate);
  var CreateDate = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 18);
   CreateDate.setValue(formattedDate);


 var lastNumberCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1);
  var nextnumber = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  lastNumberCell.setValue(nextnumber);

  var FirstCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 2);
  sheet.setActiveRange(FirstCell);
}

function showSidebar() {

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(50);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

index.html

```
    <style>
.but {
  color: black;
  border: 0px;
  position: relative;
  top: -8px;
  width: 284px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
     -webkit-transition: 0.8s ease-in-out;
} 

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(106, 178, 242);
}

.goal0 {
  background-color: #FCE5CD;
}
.goal1 {
  background-color: #F9CB9C;
}
.goal2 {
  background-color: #FFE599;
}
.goal3 {
  background-color: #D9EAD3;
}
.goalmod {
  background-color: #93C47D;
}

.newzakaz {
  background-color: #87D37C;
    margin-bottom: 15.5px;
}



</style>
 <button type="button" class="but newzakaz" onclick="google.script.run.newzakaz()">Новый заказ</button>
  <button type="button" class="but goal0"  onclick="google.script.run.goal0()">ЗП у технологов</button>
    <button type="button" class="but goal1" onclick="google.script.run.goal1()">Технологи</button>
      <button type="button" class="but goal2" onclick="google.script.run.goal2()">Экономисты</button>
        <button type="button" class="but goal3" onclick="google.script.run.goal3()">Счет</button>
          <button type="button" class="but goalmod" onclick="google.script.run.goalmod()">В историю</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually don't need to create a new standalone script file, you can use the script file that is bound to your spreadsheet.
You'll need **two** main changes, the first one is to access your spreadsheet by its ID since the sheet won't be "active" anymore and the second will be to replace your function `showSidebar()` with a new one called `doGet()`.

This `doGet` function is actually the conventional 'entry point'  of all webapps, the function that will tell the server to start with.

The code in this function should essentially be identical to the one you use in `showSidebar()` but instead of ending with

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
```

it becomes simply

```
return html;
```

since your variable called html is actually the rendering of your html file.

Then (and that will be the last thing to do) you have to save a version of your script and deploy it as a webapp. (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809760/current-url-web-app-link-doesnt-work/29810006#29810006) for details)

Comment: Hello, @Serge ! When I change code like you say there is error when web app start: Could not find script function: doGet. How I can fix it?

Comment: did you save a version and deploy(publish) it ?  Also, use de dev url for your tests as explained in the [post I refer to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809760/current-url-web-app-link-doesnt-work/29810006#29810006) while you are testing it... it will allow you to check the webapp without having to create dozens of new versions.

Comment: Yes I do all of this, save new version and publish it like web app of last version.

Comment: and use the .dev url ?

Comment: Yes. Is it right function Doget? function doget() {
  
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(50);
 // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      return(html);
}

Comment: It works when I use doget from another example:   function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');

  // Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Web App Window Title')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

Comment: here is your working sheet (copy) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kQam4JzvtT3a3uSZnF3TO89_9NKKodAqGSD85JIgvYQ/edit?usp=sharing   and webapp : https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyI-wfVrEUoJ82MB41V4lKd7g9I8Tqz7H7DBFkhchNNU9VdRSpu/exec